# Split string into 2 different strings base on 2 different symbols

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string Like

```
(1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15, 4-19, 4-20, 4-22, 4-23, 4-24)
```

Here first number is indicate table and second numbers are for another and we need to merge first numbers to one  (means, no number should be shown more than once).

can any one help me to split in to 2 different strings?

eg

```
$main-string=(1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15, 4-19, 4-20, 4-22, 4-23, 4-24);
```

need the output like below

```
$number-1= 1,2,3,4;
$number-2= 1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15,19,20,22,23,24;
```

Comment: I've reformatted, can you please check that I have the correct value for the original string?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) to find all the `digits-digits` values in the string; then simply apply [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to the first matches to get only unique values for that array:

```
$string='(1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9, 3-13, 3-14, 3-15, 4-19, 4-20, 4-22, 4-23, 4-24)';

preg_match_all('/(\d+)-(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
$tables = array_unique($matches[1]);
$numbers = $matches[2];
print_r($tables);
print_r($numbers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [9] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 13
    [7] => 14
    [8] => 15
    [9] => 19
    [10] => 20
    [11] => 22
    [12] => 23
    [13] => 24
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vJ7tQ)

If you want the answers as comma separated strings you can just use `implode` e.g.

```
echo implode(',', $tables);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
  $str = "1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-7, 2-8, 2-9,3-13, 3-14,3-15, 4-19, 4-20, 4-22, 4-23, 4-24";
  $str = str_replace(' ', '', $str); //remove spaces

  $explodeStr = explode (',', $str);
  foreach ($explodeStr as $s) {
   $a1[] = explode ('-', $s)[0];
   $a2[] = explode ('-', $s)[1];
  }
 var_dump(array_unique($a1));
 var_dump(array_unique($a2));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d20ed5b61b719478c2dd550f5b569b1850bb04cb

Comment: You could explode on `', '` and eliminate that `str_replace` call.

Comment: 1-1, 3-13, is without space

Comment: Missed it, sorry.

Comment: i remove the spaces in my code, In fact we can use your offer